# Phonegap app check if Push Notification enabled

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, plugins

I am using Phonegap PushPlugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin but on iOS when I register the app for Push Notifications, I get the error "enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later". This makes sense as the Notifications are already allowed. How do I check if it's enabled already?

I could do a check via Obj C using UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)  but I'd prefer an existing plugin if it's available. Any ideas or links?

This is only a iOS problem. Android is sweet as.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because enabledRemoteNotificationType is no longer supported in ios 8 instead enabledRemoteNotificationSetting is used.your plugin might be using the earlier method.There might be update available for this plugin or you can manually do it by putting this method if device is ios8.